# PC toasted itself, makes no sense to me

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure

I build a small PC for general office usage about 2 weeks ago:

- Pentium G3258
- Asrock B85M Pro3
- SSD
- 8GB RAM
- rather big CPU heatsink I had lying around (removed the fan, see explanation below)

I was very satisfied with the configuration which I only used to browse the web and general office stuff. The temperatures never went above 35°C with the fan on which is why I removed it after a few days to lower the noise. Without the fan I never went above 60°C even when I compiled something for one hour straight (both cores 100%) and got around 40-45°C on idle.

Everything went smooth with the fan off for like 2 weeks. Today suddenly everything got really slow (window dragging etc), so I checked CPU usage, which was between 1%-20% on both cores. I figured it was probably some weird software issue and restarted the machine, but when even grub2 took like 10sec to draw I figured something was really wrong. I unplugged the PC, opened it to check the temperature of the heatsink and burned myself really badly (certainly above 60°C). So the CPU must have been thermal throttling, which is really weird considering the low CPU usage.
I left the PC to cool off and now I don't get any display outputs anymore when I turn it on. The CPU stays cool though. The LAN LEDs on the mainboard are off but my switch detects the connection when I turn the PC on. I can't ping it though. I tried it with and without the fan plugged in.

Why did the CPU overheat all of a sudden? And why did it break after I turned it off and let it cool down instead of while it was overheating? Do you guys think it's the CPU or the mainboard?

Comment: Running a modern PC without active cooling, even if you "think it's ok" is a recipe for disaster.  As you no doubt have now found out.  Perhaps some solder melted and reflowed causing the total failure.  Bring it into a computer shop, someone who is actually qualified, and see if it can be repaired.  You can also see, since it is new, if the manufacturers will accept the parts back.  I wouldn't tell them what you did though.

Comment: Those temperatures were recorded at 100% load or idle

Comment: @ramhound 60°C was at 100% load after one hour (compiling though, not a synthetic) . 45°C was while watching a yt video. The meltdown was on idle.

Comment: @headkase I monitored the temperatures constantly during the first week of operation, while webbrowsing and compiling. Below 60°C seems quite reasonable to me. The G3258 has a realtively low TDP and I was using an overrated heatsink. Intel chips throttle around 90°C - 100°C I doubt that would be enough to reflow any solder. Many GPUs run at that temperatures. I can't see any burn marks on the motherboard, so maybe the integrated(haswell) voltage regulators on the CPU failed and overvoltaged it?

Comment: The chip you have would throttle well below 90-100 with only a 72 thermal limit.  Who know what happen you ran it without a fan.  If it still turns on PUT the Fan Back On!

Comment: "PC toasted itself, makes no sense to me" what do you expect if you remove the fan? Is this an April Fools question?

Comment: Well it makes no sense to me because it stopped working after i turned it off. Everything was fine while it was toasting itself except for the thermal throttling. And it was toasting itself while idling with my testing showing temps below 60°C on full load